# I want to classify some sentences on the basis of their semantic meaning.How can I use Doc2Vec in this? Or is there a better approach than this?

Tags: nlp, semantics, word2vec, doc2vec

I want to implement doc2vec on various reviews which we extracted from a source.And I want to classify these reviews into different classes defined by the user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I consider this as one of the interesting question. I will be giving you some approaches depending on size of observations/reviews.

- You can apply LSA (SVD on DTM (either incidence or TF-IDF vectors) you will be getting three vectors as outputs -- USV. The V transpose is the sentence embedding).

Use this embeddings as input to your model for classification.

> I recommend to use LSA when your corpus size is large.

**Resources**: [link](http://blog.josephwilk.net/projects/latent-semantic-analysis-in-python.html)

- In the similar way instead of using LSA, You can use pre trained embeddings say glove, here you will be getting word embeddings for creating document vectors use inverse weighted frequency method. Use this document vectors for classification.

**Resources**: [link](https://medium.com/@mishra.thedeepak/doc2vec-simple-implementation-example-df2afbbfbad5)